# Xcode 8 Breakpoint in file not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I have one file,`SignInViewController.swift`, in my Xcode project that out of nowhere has begun not stopping on breakpoints. I have a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad()` and a few in `viewDidAppear()`. I have several `print()` calls in both functions to make sure they are executing. Breakpoints work fine in other files including `AppDelegate.swift`.

There was a point when I trying to figure out what was wrong where I noticed that while I was building the project an error would appear saying `Invalid redeclaration of 'signInViewController.swift'` and then go away before the build finished and the app would run fine, except for the breakpoints in the file. `signInViewController.swift` is the old name of the file from months ago before I renamed it to `SignInViewController.swift`. I haven't seen it before until the breakpoint issue occurred and since I have cleaned the project's build folder and Xcode's derived data I have been unable to replicate. I have a feeling that it is factoring into the problem but I am not sure how/why.

Anyways, here is things I've tried already. Most of them are just for breakpoints not working in general but I figure I should list them anyways even though that is not the case:

> 1. Clean Project
> 2. Clean Build Folder
> 3. Clear Xcode's DerivedData
> 4. Making sure breakpoints are enabled (Cmd Y)
> 5. Build Settings are set to Debug
> 6. Always Show Disassembly enabled and disabled
> 7. Debugging enabled in run config

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1** (still no luck):

> 8. Tried deleting the Xcode preference as suggested by neprocker's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923153/5666995)

**UPDATE 2**:

I have isolated the breakpoint issue to just `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` breakpoints elsewhere in the file are working.

**UPDATE 3**:

Isolated to a specific block of code in `viewDidLoad()`. `viewDidAppear()` still not working though.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like this project is hosed. Just make a new one and migrate all your files into it!

Comment: that was a typo, fixed now

Comment: Understood. My suggestion stands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure how this ended up fixing it but I isolated the issue to a specific block of code in `viewDidLoad()`. Then I commented out that code and built and ran the project. Then I uncommented the code and built and ran it again and the breakpoints worked.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem with an old project. Select **Product(located at top menu bar) -> Scheme -> EditScheme** and I solved this issue by clicking on "Debug Executable", as shown in Picture. Maybe this will help someone else too.

[image]

Comment: Great. We should check this at the very first.

Comment: NOTE: this setting can be DIFFERENT for Run and Test. Check them both! :-D

Answer (score 17):

In my case breakpoint was not hit in just one callback, so I changed "Swift Compiler"  "Optimization Level" to "No optimization" in project target build settings for debug, and it started working in Xcode 9.3 as well as AppCode.

[image]

Comment: This is what has been working for me when this happens.

Comment: Fine for me too. Thanks

Comment: ugh. I can't believe this is the default value for a new scheme. thanks

Comment: This helped me, but Why ? Should I set it back to other option when I produce a release version of my App ?

Comment: Nijat2018 no obviously for debug build you don't need optimizations  as they slow down build time probably too, for release you leave it  as it was for debug it should be turned off but for some "unknown" reason , probable its bug , its turned on for debug also

Answer (score 8):

Below patch is work for me. From the menu bar, select **Product ->  Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Select Profile -> Set Build Configuration to BUILD**. Please review below-attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was also dealing with the same issue in xcode 9.

I resolved the issue in below ways:

- Remove XCode defaults Using below terminal command

  ```
  defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList   
  defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
  ```
- Clear(or delete) Xcode's DerivedData from

  ```
  /Users/[Your Mac Username]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
  ```
- Delete(or uninstall) Xcode.app from Applications and then restart PC
- Install fresh copy of Xcode 9
- [**Mandatory**] Set user permission to your app project like

  ```
  chmod -R 777 "/Users/[Your Mac Username]/Desktop/TestApp/"
  ```

  [*where TestApp is the app project keeping on Desktop*]
- Open the project and check Build Settings are set to Debug
- Make sure breakpoints are enabled and set debug point in your code

Comment: @Thili77 Thanks brother. Happy to hearing from you.

Answer (score 6):

What helped for me was deleting the file Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist which is located under the project directory (*.xcodeproj) in the directory: xcuserdata/Fred.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger (replace "Fred" with your username). Use a terminal program to go there.

Comment: If you're working in a workspace rather than a project, go to yourproject.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/yourusername.xcuserdata/xcdebugger instead

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by going to my Xcode project's 'Build Settings' and setting 'Generate Debug Symbols' to 'Yes'

Comment: Finally, after trying everything else suggested, this is what fixed it for me in Xcode 8.3.2

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the values may have changed in Xcode userdefaults itself,
At times, I had similar issue with debugger stopping at stacktrace
Few ways to clear this

```
1.Delete the Xcode preference
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Other Issue could be the optimization level for the target, changing it to none  will stop at the debugger

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it turns out that the **Dev** build configuration is not configured properly.

[image: Build configrution]

The **Dev** configuration should be copied from **Debug**, not **Release**.

You can search with word *debug* in your `Build settings` to see the differences.

For example:

[image: Macros]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it by deleting my Dev scheme and duplicating the Debug scheme. This way the new Dev scheme copied build settings needed to be able to debug with breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

Open viewController.swift file for initial view in the standard editor and print something inside viewDidLoad and run application.. if the print is working properly, now make sure you have selected viewController.swift file correctly in the assistant editor.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on what @neprocker said, I had "Optimize for Speed" for both debug/release. Simply changed the value for debug and I was good to go.[image: Search for Optimization Level for your target under Build Settings]