# Xcode 8.3.2 Breakpoints not working

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

Xcode will not stop on any breakpoints in this 1 project I have all the others work fine.

My Build Config : Debug, 
Breakpoints have been activated, 
Debug Workflow : Set to Always show
Strip Style: Set to All Symbols

I have tried deleting the Defaults: Delete the Xcode preference
                                     defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

I have reinstalled Xcode, ran the project on another mac and breakpoints were fine

Any ideas would be great

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this question can provide some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922865

Comment: I tried all those suggested solutions still no luck

Comment: You probably already tried this: delete the `DerivedData` folder and remove all iOS simulators.

Comment: I tried that again now, no luck yet. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not really, sorry man. Anyway I upvoted your question so we get more eyeballs on this ;-)

Comment: In the failing case, what does the command `break list` in the lldb console return?

Comment: (lldb) commands are doing anything, I tried to search but could it be disabled?

Comment: Looks like lldb-rpc-server is crashing:

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. It is inside the project settings Generate Debug Symbols  must be set to YES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer that was causing my Xcode not to register breakpoints.

Inside Build Settings, Generate Debug Symbols must be set to YES